# I cant figure out why this MARIE Sim code wont work properly

Tags: assembly, marie

So, I'm running into an issue when working with the MARIE simulator. Here is the prompt:

```asm
define a decimal variable X and set X = 0    
define a decimal variable Y and set Y = 0

Input a number in decimal form from the keyboard
store the number in location X
Input a number in decimal form from the keyboard
store the number in location Y

If X > 0, then
  X = X + 5
Else
  X = Y - 2
Endif
Display X using the output instruction
```

**EDIT**: The current code:

```asm
          org 100
          input
          store X
          input
          store Y
          load X
          skipcond 800
          Jump Else
          load X
          Add A
          store X
          jump Endif
Else,     load Y
          Subt B
          store X
Endif,    Load X
          Output
          Halt

X,      dec 0
Y,      dec 0
A,      dec 5
B,      dec 2
```

My issue comes from the fact that when you run it, the math isn't coming out correctly. For example, if you input 4 for X, the answer comes out to be 7, when it should be 9. Could anyone point where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if this works for you:

```
org 100
    input
    store X
    input
    store Y
 load X
    skipcond 800

Jump Else
    load X
    Add Addr
    store X
    jump Endif
Else,   load Y
    Subt Subtr
    store X
Endif,      Load X
    Output
    Halt
X,      dec 0
Y,      dec 0
Addr,   dec 5
Subtr,  dec 2
```

Comment: Negative, unfortunately. It suffers from the same issue as what I have currently. The X portion of the if is fine, but if it goes to the else, the output is always 2, no matter what the input for Y is.

Comment: What are you inputting and the results from said input? When ever I enter 4 for x and 10 for it outputs 9 on my marie sim. When i enter -5 for x and then input 7 for Y mt decimal output is 5. Have you saved correctly and made sure you updated your previous code or maybe try and create a new one blank edit and paste what I posted and save & assemble that, then test the inputs i provided to see if its the same.

Comment: Ill try directly copyong as soon as I get to my computer.

Comment: Yeah copy the whole block directly but into a new blank one and save it as a new name, then click assemble then go back and reload it fresh & test it. Every new run i do i load it fresh each time to reset everything since The marie program is buggy as hell and wasn't updating my saved edits before so i thought you might have a similar issue and it still have your old saved assembled and running it instead of running any new saves you've done. IF anything report back/post your results of inputs and outputs and maybe we can get it straight.

Comment: No go. I copied it directly, no change, input -5 and 7, and the output is still 2

Comment: Oh. Oh dear. I feel so dumb for not realizing that.

Comment: its been one of those kinds of weeks.. haha no prob though glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Your bug is how and when you use `skipcond`. Since you're using it right after reading Y, whatever the user enters is still in the AC, so for example if you enter 4 and 10 you'll end up with 15 (10+5), then jump right to the endif.

What you want to do is load X back into the AC, *then* check it with `skipcond`, and go into the rest of your logic. You probably also want to use more `jump`s to make sure you're executing the right blocks.

Comment: The X portion is working now(after properly loading X), but the Y is still incorrect. I double checked for proper loading, but still no cigar.